# SQL disable/reenable indexes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am doing some index evaluations and I wanted to disable an index from being used. I unchecked the 'Use index' option in the index properties but when I checked it again to enable the index usage, it seems like it's rebuilding the index. These are large indexes and some take 3 hours to rebuild.

Is there a way to quickly disable/enable indexes in SQL 2008?

Comment: No disabling the index will cause it to be rebuilt when you re-enable it. You can use query hints to force a specific alternative index to be used.

Comment: That's lousy. why does it have to be rebuilt?  I can't use hints because i'm trying to determine if the analyzer will use composite indexes (using two or more indexes).

Comment: [Disabling a nonclustered index or clustered index on a view physically deletes the index data. Disabling a clustered index on a table prevents access to the data; the data still remains in the table, but is unavailable for DML operations until the index is dropped or rebuilt.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177406.aspx)

Comment: You can create a [statistics only](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1999) copy of the database if you just want to play around with stuff like that (I think - Not sure if there are any restrictions with what you can do with a statistics only database)

Comment: Martin, please put that as an answer so I can mark it. I'm going to use a statistics only database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Database Tuning Advisor has the ability to add hypothetical indexes and hypothesise about the effect of removing indexes but I don't think that functionality is exposed in any way that we can make use of ourselves.

You could perhaps [create a statistics only copy of the database](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1999) if you just want to play around with various such scenarios (I haven't tried this myself)

Answer (score 4):

Once you re-enable an index the index rebuilds because any updates that occurred while disabled make the index obsolete, and ineffective.

Comment: this makes sense but it sucks because no updates are made. No work around?

Comment: I currently don't know of a way.  The best solution I see would be what @Martin said. I'm assuming your using trace and the sql profiler?